# Can't pass data between View Controllers using condition (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, segue, swift2, xcode7, pass-data

I've been trying to pass data to another View Controller. But as I have two Bar Buttons that lead to two different View Controllers I have to set a condition. But when I try to pass the data it won't work. Here's the code I've been using:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "ViewController") {

        let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

        destViewController.chips = chips
        destViewController.blind = blind

    }
}
```

I have my destination Storyboard id to `ViewController` but when `ViewController` view opens the data isn't passed through.

**EDIT:**

In both View Controllers `chips` and `blind` are declared as:

```
var chips = 0
var blind = 0
```

Before I added a back button the data was passed correctly. But then the application crashed every time I clicked "Back" so I decided to add a condition which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please say your vars  chips and blins are IBOutlet properties with weak attributes?

Comment: Both of them are weak should they be strong?

Comment: How do you declare chips and blind in both view controllers? Can you please edit your question?

Comment: When you say "data isn't passed through", how and where do you check that?  (If you mean it doesn't display, how do you display it?)

Comment: I tried to print() `blind` and `chips` in viedDidLoad() and tried to use a updateLabels method which updates the label to the latest values. Both of which don't show changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to Xcode/Swift, but I believe the string in your **if (segue.identifier == "ViewController")** is the problem. Instead of "ViewController" you need to use the identifier of your **segue**. Select your segue in Main.storyboard, click on the Attributes Inspector and give it a name in the Identifier field. That's the string you want to use.